# Error while installing cling kernel for jupyter notebook

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

When i was installing cling i was getting this error-

" File "/home/satoukazuma/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child

```
raise child_exception
```

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
 "

when i was executing this command in ubuntu terminal-

./cpt.py --check-requirements && ./cpt.py --create-dev-env Debug --with-workdir=./cling-build/

please help me out i'm  very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it after installing cmake

```
apt-get install cmake
```